# What are the different properties available in System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

Everything I've googled just says you can add them as a string array, but doesn't say what the available options are.

What are all the different properties that are available from Directory Services?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can put **any** of the valid LDAP attributes into `PropertiesToLoad` - see a [list of all Active Directory attributes here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - what you need is the `Ldap-Display-Name` for each attribute you're interested in.

Also: [Richard Mueller has a site with lots of good info on AD and LDAP](http://www.rlmueller.net/UserAttributes.htm) - including Excel spreadsheets of the AD attributes (and also a mapping from the Active Directory User & Computer tool to the actual AD attributes being set on those various dialog screens.

Comment: Holy crap that's a long list. Thank you!

Here are some fields that our system is already populating, why don't they show up in that list that you linked?

"adsPath","name","samAccountName","displayName","cn","sn","givenName"

Comment: @ganders: as I said - you need to use the `ldap-display-name` of those attributes - that's **not** the name you're seeing in the list. You might be better off with the Excel sheet provided by Richard Mueller on his site (which I linked to in my updated response) - it has the "full name" and the `ldap-display-name` side-by-side

Answer (score 5):

Active-Directory as any other Directories contains objects that are discribed by a [Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The Schema discribe each type ([class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680932%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) of object that can be inserted in the Directory and for each type give the [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (properties) that it supports.

The Schema can be extended by an application (like Exchange for example), you can have a look to the schema in your AD registering the MMC provided for that :

```
regsvr32 C:\Windows\System32\schmmgmt.dll
```

Then you can load MMC.EXE program and have a look to the class you are intested in, and the attributes it provides.

[image: Schema management MMC]

To see all all the objects in you Direcory with all their attributes you can use the LDP.EXE program (comming from support kit in W2K3 natively install on W2K8 AD server)

[image: LDP program]