# Bind data from LDAP to asp.repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater control and I wish to populate it with data from LDAP. I can connect to Active Directory and it will return a list of 600 plus names, but when I try and bind the data it returns the following message:

**System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult' does not contain a property with the name 'name'**

I also dont want to just return the name, but email, phone, jobtitle and a few other fields.

Is there a way I can do this?

This is my C# code:

```
        private void GetAllUsers()
    {
        SearchResultCollection results;
        DirectorySearcher ds = null;
        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(GetCurrentDomainPath());
        ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
        ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
        ds.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(objectClass=person))";
        results = ds.FindAll();
        rptAD.DataSource = results;
        rptAD.DataBind();
        foreach (SearchResult sr in results)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(sr.Properties["name"][0].ToString());
        }
    }
```

and this is the code for the repeater:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div class="container">
    <h2>AD Users</h2>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptAD" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <td>AD User</td>
                </tr>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"name") %>;
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It´s been a while since I used this library but I think some of the properties are not even mapped. Anyways if you are just trying to get the full name try the property ["displayName"]

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035481/what-are-the-different-properties-available-in-system-directoryservices-director) is link to a question regarding which properties are available for propertiesToLoad. One of the answers contains links to the list of attributes. The list is long so I didn´t check it all but I didn´t find it with a quick search.

As for returning more than one attribute just load more properties like you did above one below the other like this:

```
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName");
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSid");
```

and obtaining their values the same way as well:

```
sr.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString()
sr.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString()
sr.Properties["userPrincipalName"][0].ToString()
sr.Properties["objectSid"][0].ToString()
```

**Alternative**

I would suggest though that if you can, start using the System.Management.Automation library for obtaining anything from AD. I changed, and it made my life much simpler just because you execute your code with powershell commands.

```
using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                var adUsersList = powerShell
                     .AddCommand("Get-ADUser")
                     .AddParameter("LDAPFilter", ldapQuery)
                     .AddParameter("Properties", new string[] { "EmailAddress", "LockedOut", "Created", "Modified" })
                     .Invoke();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have sorted out my issue. I found this link very useful http://ianatkinson.net/computing/adcsharp.htm